# jQuery get first a link from li elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">link 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">link 5</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wish to return link 1 and link 5 in jQuery. I have got as far as:

```
$('ul li a:first-child').each(function(e){
$(this).css('color','blue');
});
```

However it returns all nodes, any advice appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Poozerface!

Answer (score 5):

#### Getting the Immediate Link of all Immediate List Items

It appears that you don't simply want "the first and fifth" link, but instead the first link within immediate list-items of your main UL. Your syntax was nearly correct.

```
$("ul.myList > li > a:first-child").css("color", "blue");
```

In this example the > signifies immediacy. When we say `> li`, we don't mean just any LI that happens to be in the UL, we mean the immediate li's. The same goes for the links.

Note also that I'm using a classname on my UL to distinguish it from just any UL. If we don't, the inner UL will be included in this selector.

#### Getting the First and Fifth, Regardless of Structure

Keeping in mind that jQuery uses a zero-based index (meaning the first element is index 0, the second is index 1, etc), we can use the :eq() selector to get specific indexes. In this case, we want 1 and 5 so we ask for 0 and 4:

```
$("a:eq(0), a:eq(4)", "ul.myLinks").css("color", "blue");
```

The second parameter of the selector `ul.myLinks` is our context. I'm assuming these links exist within an unordered-list having a classname of "myLinks".

```
<ul class="myLinks">
  <li><a href="#0">I'm Blue!</a></li>     <!-- this will be blue -->
  <li><a href="#1">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">Foo</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#3">Foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#4">I'm Blue!</a></li> <!-- this will be blue -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest solution is to give your "main" `ul` an ID :

```
<ul id="myUl">
<li>
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
[...]
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

and then restrict your selection to the direct children [(with the `>` keyword)](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild) instead of any descendant :

```
$('#myUl > li > a').each(function(e){
$(this).css('color','blue');
});
```